# Enumerate all installed packages from source in current javascript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, package

I'm trying to find a way to enumerate recursively all packages in a current javascript project from source.

What I would like to do is the equivalent of `npm list` or `yarn list` but from source.

What I would like to avoid:

- Directly parsing/importing myself package.json and then analysing each package.json for dependencies
- spawning a process `npm list` or `yarn list` and parsing it's output

Every search I do about such a lib is polluted in results about interactive solutions like `npm list` or `yarn list`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

- Using `yarn-logical-tree` and `npm-logical-tree` packages, and using the right one depending on the presence of `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`
- Parsing the resulted tree

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const fsPromises = fs.promises
const lockfile = require('@yarnpkg/lockfile')
const yarnLogicalTree = require('yarn-logical-tree')
const npmLogicalTree = require('npm-logical-tree')

/**
 * Return true of a file exists and is readable
 * @param {string} filename 
 */
const fileExists = async (filename) => {
    try {
        await fsPromises.access(filename, fs.constants.R_OK)
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        return false
    }
}

/**
 * Find the project directory associated to the directory passed as argument (by searching for package.json in all directories from this one to the root one)
 * @param {string} dir 
 */
const findProject = async (dir) => {
    let parsedDir = null
    dir = await fsPromises.realpath(dir)
    let found = false
    do {
        parsedDir = path.parse(dir)
        const packageFile = path.join(dir, 'package.json')
        if (await fileExists(packageFile)) {
            return dir
        }
        dir = parsedDir.dir
    } while ((!found) && parsedDir && parsedDir.base !== '')
    return null
}

/**
 * Get a package tree (by searching for a 'yarn.lock' or a 'package-lock.json')
 * @param {string} dir The directory where to look for a node project
 */
const getTree = async (dir) => {
    const project = await findProject(dir)
    const packageFilename = path.join(project, 'package.json')
    const yarnFilename = path.join(project, 'yarn.lock')
    const npmFilename = path.join(project, 'package-lock.json')
    const packageContent = await fsPromises.readFile(packageFilename, 'utf-8')
    if (await fileExists(yarnFilename)) {
        const yarnLockContent = await fsPromises.readFile(yarnFilename, 'utf-8')

        const package = JSON.parse(packageContent)
        const yarnLock = lockfile.parse(yarnLockContent)
        return yarnLogicalTree(package, yarnLock.object)
    } else if (await fileExists(npmFilename)) {
        const npmLockContent = await fsPromises.readFile(npmFilename, 'utf-8')

        const packageParsed = JSON.parse(packageContent)
        const npmLock = JSON.parse(npmLockContent)
        return npmLogicalTree(packageParsed, npmLock)
    }
    return null
}

/**
 * Find all direct or indirect dependencies from a project tree
 * @param {LogicalTree} tree The tree to parse
 * @param {Object.<string, {name: string, version: string}>} deps The deps structure to update
 * @returns {Object.<string, {name: string, version: string}>}
 */

const searchTree = async (tree, deps = {}) => {
    const { name, version, dependencies } = tree
    const id = `${name}@${version}`
    if (!deps[id]) {
        deps[id] = { name, version }
        for (let subTreeName of dependencies.keys()) {
            const subTree = dependencies.get(subTreeName)
            await searchTree(subTree, deps)
        }
    }
    return deps
}
```

And then, I'm using it like this:

```js
const start = async () => {
    let dir = '.'
    const project = await findProject(dir)
    const tree = await getTree(project)
    const deps = await searchTree(tree)
    for (let id of Object.keys(deps).sort()) {
        const { name, version } = deps[id]
        console.log(`${name} (${version})`)
    }
}

start()
```